# Getting an uncaught typerror and don't know why

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with a little javascript.

I have these four lines:

```
var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
var cookieBanner = document.createElement('div');
cookiebanner.className = "cookieBanner";
footer.appendChild(cookiebanner);
```

But in console I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
```

If I do the same in console, it works. Why would that be?

Answer (score 4):

`var footer = document.getElementById('footer');` is returning `undefined`. Therefore when you try and call `appendChild` on `undefined`, you get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
```

If there is an element with that ID on your page, make sure your page is being rendered before this script is being ran.